# How can I make gaussian noise with certain mean value in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, gaussian, noise

How can I make gaussian noise with mean= 18 and variance= 0.1 in simulink? I can't use AWGN block since I'm not able to specify mean value in it.
I want to generate the below signal which is gaussian noise with mean= 18 and variance= 0.1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the model as follows. From the **Library Browser** select the **DSP System Toolbox**, then choose the **Random Source** block.

[image]

Now, adjust the block parameters **Source type**, **Mean** and **Variance**:

[image]

Construct the model by adding a **Scope** block as follows:

[image]

After running the model for 10 sec., you will see the generated Gaussian noise waveform by double-clicking the **Scope** block. You will notice the plot is not similar to the image you posted, this is how the default plot works in Simulink.

Now, to make sure it's the correct signal, send the signal to MATLAB using the **To Workspace** block and plot it. This is how this noise waveform is plotted in MATLAB, the same as your image.

[image]

Comment: I did as you said but the output I plotted in matlab was the same as simulink output.

Comment: You can change the `Max. step size = 0.01` for example in the Solver details of the **Model Configuration Parameters** to fine tune the output for more data points like MATLAB plot.

Answer (score 0):

The mean just says how much the noise is shifted so if you take a constant function of value 18 and then add a gaussian noise of variance .1 you will get what you want.

Comment: I just used AWGN block and set the variance to 0.1 and added 18 to it but it doesn't give me the signal above.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming your noise is one-dimensional:

```
variance = 0.1;
std_deviation = sqrt(variance);
mean = 18;
n = 1000; % number of samples

noise = std_deviation .* randn(n, 1) + mean;
```